# How does x86 virtualization work

Tags: x86, virtualization

can any one suggest good reading on virtualization

Comment: Related questoin; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620408/understanding-virtualization

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest the [Intel Software Developer's Manuals](http://www.intel.com/products/processor/manuals/), specifically [volume 3B](http://www.intel.com/Assets/PDF/manual/253669.pdf), chapters 20-30. They describe the architecture in detail.

Comment: but in general what is virtualization mean and where is it used most...i know we can run one operating system on another just like an application...